# Использование свойства объекта как ресурс

Tags: c#, wpf

Я хотел бы использовать массив строк как `ItemsSource` для выпадающего списка. Поскольку объявить массив вне класса нельзя, я создал класс `TestClass` с единственным свойством `Value`, которое возвращает массив строк

```
public class TestClass 
{
    public string[] Values
    {
        get { return new string[] { "one", "two", "three" }; }
    }
}
```

Далее я добавил `TestClass` как статический ресурс, но не знаю как указать `Values` в качестве источника данных

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:TestClass x:Key="TestClass"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource TestClass}}" />
</Grid>
```

Пробовал объявить `TestClass.Values` как отдельный ресурс

```
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:TestClass x:Key="TestClass"/>
        <local:TestClass.Values x:Key="TestValues"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
```

*Ошибка: В типе TestClass не удалось найти присоединенное свойство Values.*

Пробовал обратиться к свойству `Values` при привязке

```
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource TestClass.Values}}" />
```

*Ошибка: Не удалось разрешить ресурс TestClass.Values*

Comment: Binding Values, Source=...

Comment: @АндрейNOP Работает. Опубликуйте, пожалуйста, ответ, и я его приму.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто укажите путь при создании привязки:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Values, Source={StaticResource TestClass}}" />
```

Так же, виду того, что у Binding есть перегрузка конструктора с параметром Path, эту запись можно немного укоротить:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Values, Source={StaticResource TestClass}}" />
```

Ну и обычно, все же, бизнес-данные размещают внутри вью-моделей, а саму вью-модель помещают в DataContext окна или контрола, при этом, если в привязке не указывать Source, по умолчанию она выполняется как раз к DataContext, в этом случае привязка будет выглядеть ещё короче:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Values}" />
```